# Changing the name of the field in the Entity Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the DB(which I cannot modify) I have a table Tax, one of the columns is also called Tax. When creating an Entity class for that table, I will have a class name Tax and a class variable Tax. Obviously that will not work. How do I change the name of the class variable so that Entity Framework still maps it to the correct column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attributes when creating your class

You can add a table name and a cloumn name for each property

For example

```
[Table("youtTableName")]
public class Tax
{
    [column("yourColumnName")]
    public int TaxId {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DbContext can override [DbContext.OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). You use this method, if your classes or tables don't follow the [Entity Framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx).

One of the deviations is if you tables are not plurals of your entities in DbSet, or if the properties in the entities are not the names of columns in the tables.

- So you have a table Tax with a column Tax that represents an amount.
- You create an class `Tax` that represents table Tax with a property `Value` that represents the value in column Tax.

```
    class Tax
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public decimal Value {get; set;}       // This value is in column Tax
        ...
    }
```

And your DbContext:

```
    class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Tax> Taxes {get; set;}
        ...
    }
```

By convention, entity framework expects a table with name `Taxes` and a column `Value`. You need to inform entity framework about your deviations from the conventions
in `OnModelCreating`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    const string taxesTableName = "Tax";
    const string valueColumnName = "Tax";

    modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().ToTable(taxesTableName);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(tax => tax.Value).HasColumnName(valueColumnName);
```